# ¿Como obtener string específicos con una condicion?

Tags: c#

Mi app genera `F-0001-0000000207`. El numero final `207` puede variar, puede ser 1,8888,33

Lo que necesito saber es cómo obtener siempre los últimos números o numero:

> si fuera `F-0001-0000000207` solo `207`
>
> si fuera `F-0001-000656207` solo `656207`
>
> si fuera `F-0001-000000070` solo `70`

el numero puede variar.

Espero su ayuda Gracias

Comment: Es algo muy sencillo. Has intentado algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución se divide en dos partes, primero, es *separar* la cadena en varios *tokens*, para quedarnos con la parte que contiene el número que te interesa.

Esto lo podemos hacer así:

```
string s = "F-0001-0000000207";
string[] partes = s.Split('-');
```

entonces, en la variable `partes` ahora vamos a tener 3 cadenas, `"F"`, `"0001"` y `"0000000207"`.

Ahora, convertimos esta cadena en el número que representa, hay varias formas de hacerlo, por ejemplo de esta manera:

```
int Numero;
Numero = System.Convert.ToInt32(partes[2]);
```

Ahora, la variable `Numero` tendrá el valor `207` (entero).

Un saludo.

Comment: @Pikoh, agradezco tu consejo, considero que tengo el criterio suficiente para decidir si responder o no a una pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: @DannyloRamos no comprendo tu comentario.

Comment: @gbianchi, yo voy por un objetivo más grande. Esta respuesta no es para el OP solamente, es para que en 4, 5 o 10 años, un chaval que inicia en esto, la encuentre en google y pueda dar un paso más en su aprendizaje. Repito, siempre gracias por el consejo.

Comment: Lo siento por no ser tan critico

Comment: @Pikoh, lamento si mi respuesta sonó prepotente. No era mi intención _sonar_ de esa manera. Sin embargo, si defiendo el derecho de cada uno de decidir si responder o no. Un saludo. ;)

Comment: Y créeme que no soy de los que les gusta dar el pescado, sino enseñar a pescar, simplemente hay casos donde la pregunta es tan básica, que considero que pedir algún esfuerzo es casi equivalente a pedir que no se pregunte. Y al final, veo valor en estas preguntas porque son la semilla para crear esa base de conocimiento en Español que creo que es el objetivo por el que se creó el sitio, o al menos, fue el objetivo por el que lo propuse. Un saludo ;)

Comment: Hola Jachguate. Entiendo tu punto de vista, pero estamos intentando evitar preguntas que sean solo "cómo se hace esto" sin mostrar ningun intento. Consideramos que lo más importante es pelearse con el problema y con un poco de busqueda no le haria falta hacer la pregunta. Sin embargo, si lo ha intentado y no lo ha conseguido ahi es donde su error o problema concreto puede ser util tanto para él como para otros usuarios. Esos son los problemas con los que poder ayudar. Si resolvemos estas preguntas no somos más que un repositorio de ejemplos de funciones como `split` o `substring`. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b No quisiera convertir esto en una discusión que debiera tenerse (y probablemente ya se tuvo) en meta. Agradezco que me indiques si es prohibido responder este tipo de preguntas. En ese caso no tengo de otra que no hacerlo en el futuro. Si no es prohibido, me sigo sintiendo en la libertad de hacerlo si es una pregunta que a mi juicio merece una respuesta, aún cuando haya parte de la comunidad que piense que no deben responderse, que es lo que he hecho hasta ahora. Un saludo.